# Modules not loaded in IIS 8.0 ASP.NET application after reboot

Tags: iis, asp.net, httpmodule

I have 2 ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms applications, each running on 2 win-2012 servers (IIS 8.0). The applications have modules (both custom and from 3rd parties) defined in their web.config. Each application includes a different set of modules.

***When a server is rebooted, the modules are sometimes but not always loaded*** . When the application pool is recycled for either application, the modules always load as expected. This issue occurs across the 2 servers and for each of the modules seemingly randomly.

There is no entry in the event log related to this issue.

Any idea on the cause of this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: How do you test that they are not loaded, what kind of problem does this give you?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I know they are not loaded because: 1) one module is for a 3rd party library, the library detects that the module is not loaded and sends messages to the application log; 2) one module performs redirects based on information in the URL. None of the redirect are initiated, which indicates that the module behavior is not executed. The problems vary depending on the application (incorrect redirection of users and pages with missing UI components).